# Animation like keyboard on datepicker appearing with swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uidatepicker

I wish to appear the date picker on an animation just like the keyboard does. Theres a way to achieve it?

So far this is my code, but i'm getting only the container view (the one that simulates the shadow) make a weird animation.

```
@IBAction func ShowPicker(sender: AnyObject) {

    let ContainerHeight = CGFloat(264) //320, 216
    let PickerHeight = CGFloat()
    //container for datepicker and simulates a shadow
    shadowView = UIView()
    //Use with transitionWithView
    //shadowView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height)
    //Use with animateWithDuration
    shadowView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 0.5)
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(touchOutSide))

    shadowView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    let datePicker : UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
    let datePickerContainer = UIView()

    //datePickerContainer.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.width, 320.0)
    datePickerContainer.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, self.view.frame.height - ContainerHeight, self.view.frame.width, ContainerHeight)

    //Nota ese 320 debe ser la altura natural del picker mas la altura de los botones

    datePickerContainer.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    let pickerSize : CGSize = datePicker.sizeThatFits(CGSizeZero)
    //datePicker.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.frame.width, 216.0)
    datePicker.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.frame.width, ContainerHeight)
    //datePicker.clipsToBounds = true
    datePicker.setDate(NSDate(), animated: true)
    datePicker.maximumDate = NSDate()
    //datePicker.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 0.5)
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.DateAndTime
    datePicker.addTarget(self, action: "dateChangedInDate:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    //datePickerContainer.addSubview(datePicker)

    let pickerHolder = UIView()
    pickerHolder.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 20, self.view.frame.width, ContainerHeight)
    pickerHolder.addSubview(datePicker)

    datePickerContainer.addSubview(pickerHolder)

    let doneButton = UIButton()
    doneButton.setTitle("Ok", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    doneButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    doneButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    doneButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector("dismissPicker:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    doneButton.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.width/2, 0.0, self.view.frame.width/2, 37.0)

    let btnCancel = UIButton()
    btnCancel.setTitle("Cancel", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    btnCancel.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    btnCancel.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    btnCancel.addTarget(self, action: Selector("cancelTap"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    btnCancel.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.frame.width/2, 37.0)

    datePickerContainer.addSubview(doneButton)
    datePickerContainer.addSubview(btnCancel)

    shadowView.addSubview(datePickerContainer)
    // Makes weird animations:
    //UIView.transitionWithView(self.view, duration: 0.9, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionCrossDissolve, animations: {self.view.addSubview(self.shadowView)}, completion: nil)

    self.view.addSubview(shadowView)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(2, animations: {() -> Void in self.shadowView.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: ContainerHeight)})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As your function is denoted with IBOutlet I suspect you're using Interface Builder (IB). I would consider building your date picker, container, and buttons with IB so that you can style them as well. The lifecycle of your date picker and associated views are currently scoped to the ShowPicker function, but you want them to last beyond that function, typically they exist in your view controller or one of it's subviews. Here's some sample code you can start with and embellish with your specifics.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var button: UIButton!
    let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
    var isDatePickerShowing = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle("Toggle Date Picker", for: .normal)
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 60, width: 200, height: 32)
        button.addTarget(self, action:#selector (self.tapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(button)


        let dpSize = datePicker.bounds.size
        let size = view.bounds.size
        datePicker.frame = CGRect(
            x: (size.width - dpSize.width) / 2.0,
            y: size.height,
            width: dpSize.width,
            height: dpSize.height
        )
        view.addSubview(datePicker)
    }

    func tapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        let dpSize = datePicker.bounds.size
        let size = view.bounds.size
        let y = isDatePickerShowing ? size.height : size.height - dpSize.height
        isDatePickerShowing = !isDatePickerShowing
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.75) {
            self.datePicker.frame = CGRect(
                x: (size.width - dpSize.width) / 2.0,
                y: y,
                width: dpSize.width,
                height: dpSize.height
            )
        }
    }
}
```